# How to set the value of an option in a select dropdown using a rails object's id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a modal in Rails that builds a Company Object, returns it to my select dropdown (with the correct name), prepends it and auto-selects it. However the existing Objects from the database appear in the list as rails generated options, and carry both the name of the option as well as a value - this value being their object.id so I can associate two models together. I can't for the life of me work out how to write the javascript to update the value in the dropdown as well as it's text.

My current jquery:

```
 //close the modal

$('#competitor_modal').modal('hide');
//prepend the name of the company to the select dropdown
$('#sales_opportunity_company_id').prepend($('<option></option>', {
          text: <%= j @company.company_name%>,
        }));
//select the newly prepended option
$('#sales_opportunity_company_id>option:eq(0)').attr('selected', true);
//show the submit button (I hide it whilst they are creating a new company to stop them accidentally submitting with the value "add new company"
$('#submit').show();
```

I have tried using:

```
<%= j @company.id %>
```

To retrieve the id, but that doesn't work. I've also tried all manned of attempts to get the value to automatically set (such as just trying to prepend the entire rails object to the form), with no luck.

The html generated by my current code:

```
<select id="sales_opportunity_company_id" name="sales_opportunity[company_id]">
 <option selected="selected">2</option>
 <option value="1">Any company</option>
 <option>Add new company</option>
 </select>
```

As you can see, I don't have the right id being passed through. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just to mention: `'<option></option>'` can be simplified into `'<option>'`

Comment: Take a look at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2yymdxbz/) to see how value of new `<option>` can be set.

Comment: Thanks - but this is taking the option from an HTML fragment, not from a Rails object. I need the ability to set the value to the company_id, and for some reason I can't make that work.

Comment: I know nothing about _ruby-on-rails_, but have you tried to set value as `value: <%= j @company.id %>`?

Comment: Yes, and it just stops the code working at all for some reason, returning a 500 error from the server.

Comment: Well, if `text: <%= j @company.company_name%>,` works, I don't see any reasons why `text: <%= j @company.company_name%>, value: <%= j @company.id%>,` shouldn't work. I hope `company.id` really exists?

Comment: I don't understand it either. The company exists because if I refresh the page it appears on the list.

Comment: And its `id` exists too?

Comment: It has to - if the object exists in rails it has an Id. You can select the item without the Id using the code above, but it chooses an invalid id somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// remove previously selected value:
$("#sales_opportunity_company_id :selected").removeAttr("selected");
// add new option as selected value:
$("#sales_opportunity_company_id").prepend('<option selected="selected" value="<%= @company.id %>"><%= @company.company_name %></option>');
```

Comment: `$("#sales_opportunity_company_id").find('option:selected')` can be simplified into `$("#sales_opportunity_company_id :selected')`. Also, according to original code, it should be `.prepend()`, not `.append()`, even though it's not really important, yes.

Comment: updated, thanks. I noticed you posted a link, why don't you post it as answer? looks good to me.

Comment: You're welcome. Well, I have quite a lot of answers, posted as comments :) Usually when it's too trivial or when I'm not sure it is correct one. In this question I can't be sure because of this _ruby-on-rails_ includings.

Comment: Just add `<%= @company.id %>` at the place of value and `<%= @company.company_name %>` at the place of text and it will work.

Comment: Well, I have already suggested it in question comments, but @Zoinks10 said it results in 500 Internal server error. It's a dark magic...

Comment: hahaha.. not sure, he must have missed to include `id` column in his query for the `@company` object then, otherwise it should work.

Comment: Thanks @Surya - I think it's because I was using <%= j ruby code %> rather than just <%= ruby code %> in my Javascript. Perhaps they've updated the way this works in Rails 4.